# Does gpu memory affect video processing speeds using openCV or image array manipulations?

Tags: video, opencv, memory-split

I am using my pi for video processing. The data transformations include image array manipulations and object detection.

It does not include any video display. Essentially, the pi takes in a video stream, counts objects it discovers in it, and then returns the counts to a server (as numbers).

I would like to put the gpu memory as low as possible because I only `ssh` into it. If I do that, will I be affecting video capture speed or my ability to do video/image processing?

Comment: I dont know what opencv use (CPU or GPU), but you can look at how much memory your system uses with `free -m`, `top`,`htop` to see if you need more. You could tried setting the split to the absolute minimum (to see what happens!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV does not use GPU acceleration on the Raspberry Pi platform. You can set GPU memory as low as 16 MB (you will lose 3D and video acceleration globally and the official CSI camera won't work).

Comment: the camera won't work at all if I put the gpu memory at 16 MB? Does that mean that if I increase the gpu memory it can capture at higher rez/framerate?

Comment: More than 192 MB GPU RAM seems to have no effect on performance of the camera or HW video decoders and encoders. I think.